# Proving two sequences are not homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Find an example of two real and limited sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{b_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ that are not homeomorphic fot the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

The following example was given $U_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geqslant 1$ and $V_n=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }n=1\\
\frac{1}{n}, & \mbox{ if }n>1 
\end{cases}$

Suppose there exists a homeomorphism $f:\{V_n,n\geqslant 0\}\to\{U_n:n\geqslant 0\}$

**Question:**

What is the reason behind the fact $f$ is not an homeomorphism?

How should it be proved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd probably use a constant sequence and a non-existent sequence as my examples, which would make the proof much simpler.

Comment: Hint: one of these contains a limit point, and the other does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** One element of $\{V_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an accumulation of $\{V_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, but no point of $\{U_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has the similar property.

Comment: I know 0 is accumulation point of $V_n$ however since $Un=\frac{1}{n}$I thought there would be an open $B_\epsilon(\frac{1}{n},0)$ for a $\epsilon>0$ so that 0 is also a limit point of $U_n$.

Comment: That is difficult for me to conceive. How should I prove such statement?

Comment: Yes that is what I cannot prove. Why is there no open set in $U_n$ that contains $0$?

Comment: @pedro because $U_n$ doesn't contain $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Sir we can say since $U_n$ is not closed so it is not homeomorphic to $V_n$ which is closed as homeomorphisms preserve compactness.

Comment: @yadati in their respective subspace topologies both are closed.

Comment: A closed set can be homeomorphic to a non-closed one, but your argument using compactness is correct.